# Tag Helper IntelliSense is not working in vs 2022

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, visual-studio-2022, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Why tag helper is not show and IntelliSense in my VS 2022

This is my NuGet package

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="5.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="5.0.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.14">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.12">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="5.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

please help me

I searched Microsoft and found that I need to install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rezor.Tools NuGet

But this Nuget Package is showing my Manage NuGet Package

Why???

Comment: Have you added taghelper in _ViewImports.cshtml?

Comment: Yes, I went like Microsoft